# Removing a notification from notification center on click

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, notificationcenter

Is it possible to remove the push notification from the notification center when one is clicked and the app launches?

Most apps seem to leave the notification in place. I read on another question that this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

may work however it doesn't work for me.

The Facebook app definitely seems to remove the push notifications once clicked on.

Comment: Is there any particularity for ipad?

Comment: hi! Any solutions on this?? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
int badgeCount = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeCount];
```

If you add this to both

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

And

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

You will retain the badge count, and clear the push notification when it is clicked in the notification center.

Comment: What if I want to remove only the notification the user clicked on, and not all notifications in the notification center?

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925854/remove-single-remote-notification-from-notification-center  You cannot.

Comment: @AlaaNassef Of course you can,
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:yournotification];

Comment: Its not working for me. Notification is not cleared when I click on it.