# Clear Push notifications from notification centre after selecting one

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to clear all push notifications of my application, once user selects one of the push notification.

I have seen other threads here which says it's not possible in iOS.
but I have one application downloaded from app store, which does the same thing.

Comment: You might consider posting some more info about the app that has this feature.

Comment: And also links where it said to be impossible. This way your question would be more informative

Comment: just set your app's badge count as 0. it will clear all notifications from your notification center

Comment: @rjstelling Application is "WhatsApp", popular app for mobile chatting in India

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing a notification from notification center on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017348/removing-a-notification-from-notification-center-on-click)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If it is a local notification then to remove badge icon you have to do it like this

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

If it is push notification the you can do it by code written below

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
```

You may call these methods anywhere you want. For example if you want to clear notification at the moment when the app is launched then write it in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

if your app doesn't use the badge number you have to first set, then reset it to remove it from notification centre.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Comment: I have added code for both the scenarios. use second code for push notification

Comment: I have tried [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;.... did not worked for me

Comment: @VishalKardode : please check my answer now. or refer [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773584/can-i-programmatically-clear-my-apps-notifications-from-the-ios-5-notification

Comment: Thanks but still its not clearing push notifications, even after setting and resetting application badge number.

Comment: Setting and resetting the badge number works for me thank you.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is

`application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;`

in

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

**EDIT**

If you are not closing your app but just sending it to background. Then add this in your below function as well.

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
    {
         //opened from a push notification when the app was on background
         application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that what i said.. and if your application is in background mode then check in this delegate method 

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

      

}

Comment: As per my understanding, application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0; will reset Badge icon, not the notifications in notification centre. I did gave it a try , but did not work

Comment: Well. Here notification has been deleted from notification center whenever i am opening particular app with notification.