# iOS Clear individual / all notifications from Notification Center

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I would like to clear delivered notifications from notification centre based on what a user does.
So, if they view a certain screen, remove the relevant notification etc.

There may be more than one delivered notification for the app, but I may not want to clear all of them.

How can I list all the delivered notifications that are showing in notification centre from my app, and then programatically remove the relevant notification?

I have looked at this thread [Can I programmatically clear my app's notifications from the iOS 5 Notification Center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773584/can-i-programmatically-clear-my-apps-notifications-from-the-ios-5-notification) however it does not seem to show how I can list delivered notifications so that I can then programatically remove the relevant one(s).

Comment: You can't do this. You can either delete them all or none of them. You can't delete individual ones

Comment: Shame! Would be nice to be able to do that. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 0):

As per Martin H
You can't do this. You can either delete them all or none of them. You can't delete individual ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have several types of notifications and I selectively remove notifications based on user interactions. Simply reference the name of your Notification variable and remove it.

```
var notification_1:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
....
var notification_1:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
....
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification_1)
```

It may not be the best method, but it seems to work. See this answer too: [Removing a notification from notification center on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017348/removing-a-notification-from-notification-center-on-click?lq=1)